# how to force a div to display next to another element

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a vertical drop down menu, and i need to create a photo gallery next to it, however, the gallery is displaying below the menu instead.  I've tried adjusting the dimensions to make room for it, but nothing is working.

```
    #gallery {
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:500px;

}

.square {
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#dbdbdb;
}

.square2 {
    width:149px;
    height:149px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color:#dbdbdb;
}
```

Comment: what is your HTML code

Comment: Try `display:inline-block`

Comment: Really need the HTML code to see how you have your DOM setup. @user2612234

Comment: Also please use something like a jsFiddle in the future http://jsfiddle.net/EMyRm/ @user2612234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this:

1. Apply the style `display:inline-block;` to the DIVs in question
2. Specify `float:left;` and a `width:` on the DIVs that should be next to each other

(For either method) make sure the container is wide enough to fit both of them next to each other

Comment: okay thanks.  there's not enough space for me to post my code.  I'm using a dreamweaver spry menu, so that might also be the issue.